# How can I store an array of boolean values in a MySql database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, arrays, boolean, field

In my case, every "item" either has a property , or not. The properties can be some hundreds, so I will need , say, max 1000 true/false bits per item.

Is there a way to store those bits in one field of the item ?

Comment: Do you need to run any kind of query against this? Or just store/retrieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to do this in a way that's searchable, then no.

A couple searchable methods (involving more than 1 column and/or table):

- Use a bunch of [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html) columns. You're limited to 64 items (on/offs) in a set, but you cna probably figure out a way to group them.
- Use 3 tables: Items (id, ...), FlagNames(id, name), and a pivot table ItemFlags(item_id, flag_id). You can then query for items with [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

If you don't need it to be searchable, then all you need is a method to serialize your data before you put it in the database, and a unserialize it when you pull it out, then use a char, or varchar column.

- Use facilities built in to your language (PHP's serialize/unserialize).
- Concatenate a series of "y" and "n" characters together.
- Bit-pack your values into a string (8 bits per character) in the client before making a call to the MySQL database, and unpack them when retrieving data out of the database. This is the most efficient storage mechanism (if all rows are the same, use char[x], not varchar[x]) at the expense of the data not being searchable and slightly more complicated code.

Comment: bit packs can be queried directly. so, the only 2 solutions in real - bitpack or normalize.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather go with something like:

```
Properties
ID, Property
1, FirsProperty
2, SecondProperty

ItemProperties
ID, Property, Item
1021, 1, 10
1022, 2, 10
```

Then it would be easy to retrieve which properties are set or not with a query for any particular item.

Comment: I think the query would not make the server very happy, and same for the people who would wait for it to execute...

Answer (score 0):

At worst you would have to use a char(1000) [ynnynynnynynnynny...] or the like.  If you're willing to pack it (for example, into hex isn't too bad) you could do it with a char(64) [hexadecimal chars].

If it is less than 64, then the SET type will work, but it seems like that's not enough.

You could use a binary type, but that's designed more for stuff like movies, etc.. so I'd not.

So yeah, it seems like your best bet is to pack it into a string, and then store that.

It should be noted that a VARCHAR would be wasting space, since you do know precisely how much space your data will take, and can allocate it exactly.  (Having fixed-width rows is a good thing)

Comment: Good answer if he does not have to do queries against these flags. If he wants to write a WHERE clause using the packed string, this could be tricky (and hard to index).

Comment: Very true. In that case, I would agree that another (three tables instead of 1) solution would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you can accomplish this using the following:

```
$bools = array(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1);
$for_db = serialize($array);

// Insert the serialized $for_db string into the database. You could use a text type
// make certain it could hold the entire string.
// To get it back out:

$bools = unserialize($from_db);
```

That said, I would strongly recommend looking at alternative solutions.

Depending on the use case you might try creating an "item" table that has a many-to-many relationship with values from an "attributes" table. This would be a standard implementation of the common Entity Attribute Value database design pattern for storing variable points of data about a common set of objects.