# How to implement MySQL SET concept with over 64 members?

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to replicate the behaviour of a MySQL `SET` col type, with over 64 members?

I need to do what I would naturally do with a MySQL `SET` with around 85 different options. (The limit is 64.) What would be the best way to implement this?

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848780/best-way-to-store-a-set-bigger-than-64), which suggests a `JOIN`, but my members are only 6-char strings, is the most efficient way *really* to create an entire new, 1-column table of these members (I'll call it table 2), and then a third table of 2 cols linking an id from table 1 (where I would have created my `SET` column) and table 2?

Comment: What I would do naturally with a set is normalize it so it wasn't a set anymore. Does that help?

Comment: @Blueberry same here.

Comment: Thank you, I've just been completely overthinking the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalise into a second table that uses an `ENUM`:

From a single-table design like this:

- `ID`, ..., `Set_Col`

to these:

- Table1: `ID`, ...
- Table2: `Table1_ID`, `Enum_Col`

You can then have  a zero-or-more relationship from your Table1 PK (`ID`) to values in your "set", which is now not a set but a normalised `ENUM` value. You get the space benefits of a `SET` or `ENUM`, the multiplicity of a `SET`, but you overcome the 64 member limit of `SET`.

Comment: Thank you, I've just been overthinking the whole problem it seems. Will accept in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have those 6-char strings, there will be cases in the future when you will have to put them in a result set, so I would put them into a separate table and use the "JOIN + connection table" approach.

If there were no strings given for the elements of set, then I would implement an array of booleans in SQL. There are multiple solutions to do this, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154987/how-can-i-store-an-array-of-boolean-values-in-a-mysql-database).